# Getting started `use-package` question

Tags: package, use-package

I was reading the [`use-package` documentation](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package#getting-started), which says, "Here is the simplest use-package declaration:"

```el
;; This is only needed once, near the top of the file
(eval-when-compile
  ;; Following line is not needed if use-package.el is in ~/.emacs.d
  (add-to-list 'load-path "<path where use-package is installed>")
  (require 'use-package))

(use-package foo)
```

As an Emacs beginner, I have a few questions about this part if I may.

1. Do I need `(package-initialize)` before these lines?  It seems to me that without doing that, the `use-package` macro wouldn't be available.
2. I do not need the 4th line in the above snippet, right? As I have installed `use-package` from MELPA Stable, and the package is installed to the default location `~/.emacs.d/elpa/use-package-2.4`.
3. In this example, is `(use-package foo)` equivalent to `(require 'foo)`?

Answer (score 15):

> 1. Do I need `(package-initialize)` before these lines?

If your version of Emacs (<kbd>M-x</kbd>`emacs-version`<kbd>RET</kbd>) is older than 27, and you are using the built-in package manager, then you indeed need to call `(package-initialize)` before you can call on any installed packages, such as `use-package`.

From Emacs 27 onwards, `package-initialize` will effectively be called before `user-init-file` is loaded. This can be disabled by setting `package-enable-at-startup` to `nil` in the new `early-init-file`.

> It seems to me that without doing that, the `use-package` macro wouldn't be available.

It depends. The example is written from the perspective of someone who doesn't use the built-in package manager (e.g. the author of `use-package`), and who manually installs packages so that they can be found by Emacs on their `load-path`. This is what `package-install` and `package-initialize` effectively automate for the user.

> 2. I do not need the 4th line in the above snippet, right? As I have installed `use-package` from MELPA Stable, and the package is installed to the default location `~/.emacs.d/elpa/use-package-2.4`.

Correct. If you install packages using the package manager and call `package-initialize`, then you do not need to manually edit your `load-path`.

> 3. In this example, is `(use-package foo)` equivalent to `(require 'foo)`?

Let's find out: with point after the closing parenthesis of `(use-package foo)`, call <kbd>M-x</kbd>`pp-macroexpand-last-sexp`<kbd>RET</kbd>. This will print what `use-package` is actually doing under the bonnet to the buffer `*Pp Macroexpand Output*`:

```el
(progn
  (defvar use-package--warning0
    (lambda (keyword err)
      (let ((msg (format "%s/%s: %s" 'foo keyword
                         (error-message-string err))))
        (display-warning 'use-package msg :error))))
  (condition-case-unless-debug err
      (unless (require 'foo nil t)
        (display-warning 'use-package
                         (format "Cannot load %s" 'foo)
                         :error))
    (error
     (funcall use-package--warning0 :catch err))))
```

Stripping away all of the error reporting, we're left with:

```el
(require 'foo nil t)
```

Which is like `(require 'foo)`, but doesn't signal an error if the [named feature](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Named-Features.html) `foo` can't be found.